# Visual Studio 2017 not opening .modelproj

Tags: visual-studio-2017

What workload/component needs to be installed in order for Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise to open existing .modelproj (UML-based design projects)?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

After selecting the ***.NET desktop development*** workload, be sure to add the optional ***Architecture and analysis tools*** component to the install list.

Comment: The best answer. Remember to look for this option on the right side but not in "Individual Components".

Comment: Also the correct answer for Visual Studio 2019, if anyone is wondering. Make sure you to go "Individual Components" and Look on the right for ".NET desktop development" to finding the correct one.

Comment: I was able to load a .modelproj project after checking "Individual Components" -> "Code Tools" -> "Dependency Validation" on Visual Studio Installer. I'm using Visual Studio 2019 Community.

Comment: I did the same thing in visual studio 2022 community edition but I couldn't open it

Answer (score 18):

I also get this error. I explain how I fix;

1. Open **Visual Studio Installer**
2. Click **Modify**
3. Go **individual components** tab
4. Then check all checkboxes inside **Code Tools**

**EDIT *03/03/2018*:**

This @Ben solution from the comment:

1. Open **Visual Studio 2017**
2. **Tools** menu
3. **Get tools and Features...** selection
4. **Individual Components** tab
5. **Code Tools** group, Then check all checkboxes inside

When you restart visual studio 2017, it must be fixed. Hope it will help someone

Comment: Confirmed, on VS2017 Community. How I got there: Open VS > `Tools` menu > `Get tools and features...` selection > `Individual Components` tab  > `Code Tools` group

Comment: I added your comment to answer. @Ben

Answer (score 7):

The following worked for me in Visual Studio 2017 (version 15.4.2):

1. Open **Visual Studio Installer**
2. Go to the tab **Individual components**
3. In the **Code tools** section tick **Live Dependency Validation**. Although this is a different feature, it installed the required dependencies for me.

Comment: In Visual Studio 2019 Enterprise, there is no **Architecture and analysis tools** option, but if you search for "**Architecture**" in **Individual Components**, the "**Live Dependency Validation**" appears, so I checked and installed it like you did. And that worked for me.

Comment: that let me open the solution, but i see the files as xml, i cannot see the diagrams

Answer (score 0):

to open the project you have to do as described above and install the Live Dependency validation in the Code tools BUT...

"UML designers have been removed

The UML designers have been removed from Visual Studio.

```
UML diagrams are now presented as XML files
The UML Model Explorer no longer exists
Modeling project references are no longer used for dependency validation
The "Layer References" node in Solution Explorer is no longer displayed
The "Validate" build action on a Dependency (Layer) diagram is no longer used - the Build task has been removed
The project structure is maintained for round-tripping between versions
You can still open, create, edit, and save a Dependency (Layer) diagram as XML
TFS work items linked to a Dependency (Layer) diagram are not accessible on the design surface
Back linking from to DSL or a Layer is no longer supported
UML extensibility in the Modeling SDK is no longer supported"
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/is-is/visualstudio/modeling/what-s-new-for-design-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017