# Visual Studio 2017 Build Tools - Architecture and analysis tools

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I'm encountering an issue when trying to build .modelproj projects using msbuild via Visual Studio 2017 Build Tools.

This is the error I see:

> ...[ProjectName].modelproj error MSB4057: The target "Rebuild" does
>   not exist in the project.

I have found this thread relating to some issues opening .modelproj files via the IDE in VS2017 - [Visual Studio 2017 not opening .modelproj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42727430/visual-studio-2017-not-opening-modelproj?rq=1) - however is there a way to get this fix onto just Build Tools rather than the full IDE? Ideally we'd like to avoid having to install the full IDE when all we require are the Build Tools on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> however is there a way to get this fix onto just Build Tools rather than the full IDE? Ideally we'd like to avoid having to install the full IDE when all we require are the Build Tools on the server.

You can not build Modeling projects using msbuild via Visual Studio 2017 Build Tools. Because **starting with Visual Studio 2017, the UML Designers have been removed from Visual Studio**, If you are a significant user of the UML designers, you can continue to use Visual Studio 2015 or earlier versions.

You can get the detail information from [Port, Migrate, and Upgrade Visual Studio Projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/porting/port-migrate-and-upgrade-visual-studio-projects) and [Microsoft Application Lifecycle Management](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/10/14/uml-designers-have-been-removed-layer-designer-now-supports-live-architectural-analysis/#comments)：

[image]