# Unable to open VS 2015 .modelproj in VS 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, uml

VS2017 is showing project as incompatible. Is there any way to load the project in VS2017

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio 2017 not opening .modelproj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42727430/visual-studio-2017-not-opening-modelproj)

Comment: I already tried the option provided there but they are not working