# How to open modelproj in Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

What workload/component needs to be installed in order for Visual Studio 2022 Community Edition to open existing .modelproj?

I have installed everything under the Code Tools group

- Open Visual Studio 2022
- Tools menu
- Get tools and Features...
- Individual Components tab
- Code Tools group

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Visual Studio 2017 not opening .modelproj](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42727430/visual-studio-2017-not-opening-modelproj)

Comment: I did the same thing in visual studio 2022 community edition but I couldn't open it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The workload component name is `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.DependencyValidation.Enterprise`. However, as you can probably see, this component is limited to enterprise editions of Visual Studio (just like code coverage).

It would be listed under the "Code Tools" section as "Live Dependency Validation".

Answer (score 0):

I resoled it but going to View -> Terminal and then running

dotnet install android 
dotnet install ios 
dotnet install maccatalyst